# Angular YouTube Control and JavaScript Events

Tags: javascript, angular, performance, youtube

I am experiencing performance issues using the Angular YouTube control.  When using the Safari Timeline monitoring, I notice nearly continuous JavaScript events being fired.  My CPU time is high and performance is low.  When I comment out the YouTube control, the Timeline shows radically lower events, CPU usages drops significantly, and overall performance is acceptable.

So, there seems to be something unexpected occurring when using that YouTube control.  I have been researching for sometime and cannot find any article that speaks to what I am encountering.

I am hoping someone will have some insight.

I have included copies of code and screen prints of the Safari Timeline.

The HTML for the control...

```
<youtube-player 
    [videoId]="videoId"
    suggestedQuality="large"
    [height]="156"
    [width]="275">
</youtube-player>
```

The TypeScript...

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-youtube-player',
    templateUrl: './youtube-player.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./youtube-player.component.css']
})
export class YoutubePlayerComponent implements OnInit {

    private apiLoaded = false;
    @Input() videoId: string;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit(): void {

        if (!this.apiLoaded) {
            const tag = document.createElement('script');
            tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
            document.body.appendChild(tag);
            this.apiLoaded = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The screen print of the Safari Timeline with the YouTube control rendered.

[image]

The screen print of the Safari Timeline with the YouTube control commented out.

[image]

I have tried this with multiple versions of the Angular YouTube library.  I am currently using the most recent version - 15.1.4.

Any ideas?

Comment: Has no one else ever seen this?  It is hard to believe that this is only happening in my software.

Comment: Can you post what npm library you're using?

Comment: I am just using the Angular YouTube library - "@angular/youtube-player": "15.2.5".  I have also tried using the native YouTube iFrame approach.  I am beginning to think this is normal.  I pulled the stats from YouTube directly and see the same continuous Java events.